# Preservation questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I have a question about how to best preserve an object which is of some historical value - is that on topic here?

Comment: What kind of object is it? Maybe Chemistry group would be appropriate.

Comment: They appear to be photographic litho print plates.  I'm just having a hard time finding a suitable group on SE to ask...

Comment: @JamesSnell I was going to suggest Photography.SE, but then I noticed you've already tried the site. Not sure your question is on topic there, but hey, it's not closed yet.

Comment: An upvote for asking before posting.

Comment: If it's of genealogical value, it might be appropriate on [genealogy.se]

Comment: It's not as it goes, although I might pay them a visit with a question I have... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that question is not really on topic here. Taken from [the Help Center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> History Stack Exchange is for historians and history buffs. If you have a question about:
>
> - Historical events Cultures and historical practices
> - Famous people
> - Ancient Languages
> - Factual current political history questions
>
> Then you are in the right place.
>
> It is not about:
>
> - Genealogy
> - Asking for reference material
> - Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page
> - Predicting the future based on historical trends
> - Mythology
> - Conspiracy Theories or Pseudo-science
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

### However, all hope is not lost. As the Help Center continues:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for History Stack Exchange, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see any links to the FAQ from the homepage so I thought best to ask in meta first.

Comment: It's actually called the help center now. :) That's probably the source of confusion.